# How to get the actual timestamp minus 2 months and the first day without time part in h2 database?

Tags: sql, h2

In H2 I would like to get the actual timestamp minus 2 months and on the first day of month without the time part?

eg.: 2020-03-09 13:46:55  =>  2020-01-01 00:00:00

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select FORMATDATETIME(DATEADD(mm,-2,CURRENT_DATE) ,'Y-MM-01');
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TIMESTAMP '2020-03-09 13:46:55' - INTERVAL '2' MONTH)
```

/

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' MONTH)
```

should be used in recent releases of H2. It isn't supported by historic versions, however.

`FORMATDATETIME` is slow, has different known bugs, and it produces a `VARCHAR` value that needs an additional implicit or explicit cast back to a datetime value.